# Performance/technical issue with Google Chrome Frame? (for IE 8 and lower)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-frame

I'm making a website using HTML5 and CSS3 and thinking to use Google Chrome Frame for IE8 and lower because I don't want to for graceful degradation or giving alternative visuals using Modernizer for IE8 and lower. But want to know Is there any performance and any other technical issue with Google chrome Frame?

If Google chrome frame has issue then I will go for graceful degradation or giving alternative visuals using Modernizer.

Google Chrome frame website says

> - Start using open web technologies—such as the HTML5 canvas tag—right    away, even technologies that aren't yet supported in
>     Internet    Explorer 6, 7, 8, or 9.
> - Take advantage of JavaScript performance improvements to make your    apps faster and more responsive.

I want to know comments from any experienced who have use chrome frame.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get it other way around: you as a user can install Google Chrome Frame to use new features, but web site normally is not able to rely on the fact that the Frame is present on user's machine.

Users with older browsers liklely will not be able or willing to install the required plugin.

Comment: Yes if user don't install the Chrome frame plugin then it's fine and he will get some visual differences. My question is if he install the plugin will he get better performance and visuals as google chrome frame says `JavaScript performance improvements to make your apps faster and more responsive.'

Comment: It is essentially Chrome browser inside IE's shell - so yes for older versions, for IE9/10 make your own judgement.